# search in bit array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, search

if there are two array, first array size 100 bit and second array size 32 bit,i want to search 32 bit array in first array 100 bit

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(100);  
BitArray bitss = new BitArray(32); 


bitss.Set(16,true);
bitss.Set(25,true);
bitss.Set(26,true);
bitss.Set(28,true);
bitss.Set(29,true);
bitss.Set(31,true);

for (int i = 0; i < (bits.Length)-1;i++ )

if ((bits[i] == bitss[0] &&
    bits[i + 1] == bitss[1] &&
    bits[i + 2] == bitss[2] &&
    bits[i + 3] == bitss[3] &&
    ...
    bits[i + 31] == bitss[31]))

    Console.WriteLine("Found");
```

is there better method for search bitss array in bit array without use ( if and ==  ) in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely be shortened with another for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (bits.Length)-1;i++ ) {
    bool found = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        if (bits[i + j] != bits[j]) {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using LINQ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < bits.Length - bitss.Length; i++)
{
    if (bits.Cast<bool>().Skip(i).Take(bitss.Length).SequenceEqual(bitss.Cast<bool>()))
        Console.WriteLine("Found!");
}
```

But just to make it clear: **it will be a little slower then using simple `for` loop!**. Bit I would not care about that at all.

Comment: that would make `BitArray` redundant..Why not create a list of bool then..If he's going to have 1000's of bool casting BitArray to bool would be costly..

Comment: @Anirudh LINQ is lazy, so it will get and compare only one item at the time internally. And when you use indexer on `BitArray` using `[]` operator there is `bool` casting performed anyway, so this part of your concerns is not valid either.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think Anirudn meant to compare between **BitArray** and **List<bool>**, not **BitArray** and **LINQ**.

Comment: I can't see any `List<bool>` neither in my solution nor previous comment, so I think it's about LINQ.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek since op has two bitArray it's more convinient to use `BitArray.Xor` or other bitwise opearation then linq..If you really want to use linq then there's no reason to use BitArray

Answer (score 1):

Just another option, which i find more readable and debugable :)

for your input, add this method:

```
public  string BitArrayToString(BitArray input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var bit in input)
    {
        if ((bool) bit) sb.Append("1");
        else sb.Append("0");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and then you can simply do:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(100);
BitArray bitss = new BitArray(32);

bitss.Set(16, true);
bitss.Set(25, true);
bitss.Set(26, true);
bitss.Set(28, true);
bitss.Set(29, true);
bitss.Set(31, true);

var bigString = BitArrayToString(bits);
var smallString = BitArrayToString(bitss);

var cantained = bigString.Contains(smallString);
```

Done :)